# Prestack of coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, moduli-space

Alper in his textbook *Stacks and moduli* defines the prestack of coherent sheaves over a smooth projective curve:

> Let C be a fixed smooth, connected, and projective curve over an
> algebraically closed field $\mathbb k$. We define the prestack
> $Coh(C)$ over $Sch/\mathbb k$ where objects are pairs $(E, S)$ where
> $S$ is a scheme over $\mathbb k$ and $E$ is a coherent sheaf on $C_S =
> > C \times_{\mathbb k} S$ flat over $S$.

I struggle to see why smooth projective curves are somehow distinguished there, as the construction doesn't seem to use the fact that $C$ is a curve anywhere, so it should make sense also for more general schemes. Is there some reason to restrict attention to this specific type of base scheme that I've missed?

Comment: Sure. You can find more general def in the standard textbook [Champs Algebriques](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-24899-6). I assume the author wants to say something in the following that is specific to curves, though

Comment: Thanks. Probably he does later in the book, and now just introduce that as example that will be then relevant, but I didn't find anything more specific at this moment thus got confused